# Running Ping Sweep Python Script Faster

Tags: python-3.x, performance

I'm trying to run ping sweep over a specific network using pyping module and it works fine, but very slow. How can I make it run faster?

```
import pyping

Network="127.0.0."
for i in range(1,21):
    IP=Network+str(i)
    response = pyping.ping(IP)
    if response.ret_code == 0:
        print(IP)
```

Comment: quite an old package

Comment: Any other suggestions?

Comment: Consider multi-threading.

Comment: What do you say about the below?

Answer (score 0):

import subprocess

Network="172.23.13."

for i in range(1,255):

```
IP=Network+str(i)

p = subprocess.Popen('ping -c 1 –W 1'+IP,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)

# the stdout=subprocess.PIPE will hide the output of the ping command

p.wait()

if p.poll()==0:

    print IP
```